# How to display current selected photos when presenting a PHPickerViewController manually?

Tags: ios, swift, ios14, photokit, phpickerviewcontroller

Is there a way to show the user's current photo selections when presenting a `PHPickerViewController` manually? For example, when using the following code the picker doesn't show any of the user's currently selected photos.

```
 var pickerConfig = PHPickerConfiguration()
 pickerConfig.selectionLimit = 0
 pickerConfig.filter = .any(of: [.images])
            
 let imagePicker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: pickerConfig)
 imagePicker.delegate = self

 // When presented, the user's current selected photos are empty, nothing is selected
 viewController.present(imagePicker, animated: true)
```

However, if I use Apple's built in `presentLimitedLibraryPicker` function it does show the user's current photo selections:

```
// This does show the user's current selections
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker(from controller: self)
```

Is there a way to get this behavior without using `presentLimitedLibraryPicker`?

Comment: Try increasing the `selectionLimit` to something greater than 0

Comment: What are "current selections" in this context? You mean what the user is selecting right now in the picker after you present it? Or what the user selected before? Or what?

Comment: @matt I'm referring to photos that the user has selected before. So if they have 20 photos selected and I present the PHPickerViewController, none of those selections are showing up.

Comment: If they have 20 photos selected where before? When before? PHPickerViewController has no memory, it doesn't know anything about what happened "before".

Comment: @aheze Thanks for the suggestion but I've tried that and it doesn't work. A selection limit of 0 on the PHPickerConfiguration means the maximum supported by the system.

Comment: @JKoko wait I thought you meant the photos aren't highlighted when you press them -- "the picker doesn't show any current selections"

Comment: @matt For my specific use case, the user selects these photos on the app's first launch. If they select limited photo library access, the system presents the photo picker. In my Settings screen, I give the user the option to add/remove photos later on if they want, but when I present the picker manually all of the selections are missing.  When I use the presentLimitedLibraryPicker API, the selections show as expected.

Comment: But changing what photos can be accessed under limited access is not the job of the PHPicker. That is the job of the `presentLimitedLibraryPicker` picker.

Comment: @matt That is true, I am thinking about this incorrectly then. I'll need to stick with `presentLimitedLibraryPicker` and utilize the PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver to listen for updates to the selections.

Comment: Correct-a-mundo.

Comment: If you just need one-off access to those photos you should just stick with the PHPicker instead, so that users don't need to grant any permissions at all. If you manage a list of access-granted pictures, then you need to handle the limited access permission and show the limited picker by tapping on some UI element to "refresh" content, then listen to the notification to update your content.

Comment: Mind to share the answer @JKoko ?